# Aligning data from multiple years across 24 months in R

Tags: r, date, tidyverse

I have a dataset with observations of ids during certain months. Here is a minimal data set example:

```
data <- structure(list(id = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L), 
    month = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 
    3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L), month_new = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 
    23L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 
    18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 21L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L))
```

Now, the months are from different years, but I need to align them across two years, i.e. across 24 months. So, my goal is that for every id, the month number stays the same if they are within the first year, but that the month number increases by 12 if the observations pass the 12th month during previous observations and that in that case any month number gets increased by 12 for the second year. However, there are multiple observations per month in the first and second year, so that I only want to +12 each month number if within the individual the month numbers have passed 12 in the "month" column.

Thanks to Onyambu I have the following code:

```
output_desired <- locs %>% 
  group_by(ptt) %>%
  mutate(new = first(month_num) - 1 + as.integer(factor(month_num, unique(month_num))))
```

However, this code has problems if the same month re-appears in the second year, i.e. after 12 occurs for the first time. At it has difficulties when months are skipped in the observations, e.g. jump from 12 to 2 as you can see here:

```
      id month month_new
 1    11     8         8
 2    11     8         8
 3    11     8         8
 4    11     9         9
 5    11    10        10
 6    11    10        10
 7    11    10        10
 8    11    11        11
 9    11    11        11
10    11    11        11
11    11    11        11
12    11    12        12
13    11    12        12
14    11     1        13
15    11     1        13
16    11     1        13
17    11     1        13
18    11     1        13
19    11     2        14
20    11     2        14
21    11     3        15
22    11     3        15
23    11     6        16
24    11     6        16
25    11     8         8
26    11     8         8
27    11     8         8
28    11     9         9
29    11    11        11
30    22     1         1
31    22     1         1
32    22     2         2
33    22     2         2
34    22     6         3
35    22     7         4
36    22     9         5
37    22     9         5
38    22    12         6
39    22    12         6
40    22     3         7
41    22     3         7
42    22     6         3
43    22     7         4
44    22     8         8
45    22     9         5
46    22     9         5
```

My desired output would be this:

```
output_desired <- structure(list(id = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L), 
    month = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 
    3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L), month_new = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 
    23L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 
    18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 21L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L))

> output_desired
   id month month_new
1  11     8         8
2  11     8         8
3  11     8         8
4  11     9         9
5  11    10        10
6  11    10        10
7  11    10        10
8  11    11        11
9  11    11        11
10 11    11        11
11 11    11        11
12 11    12        12
13 11    12        12
14 11     1        13
15 11     1        13
16 11     1        13
17 11     1        13
18 11     1        13
19 11     2        14
20 11     2        14
21 11     3        15
22 11     3        15
23 11     6        18
24 11     6        18
25 11     8        20
26 11     8        20
27 11     8        20
28 11     9        21
29 11    11        23
30 22     1         1
31 22     1         1
32 22     2         2
33 22     2         2
34 22     6         6
35 22     7         7
36 22     9         9
37 22     9         9
38 22    12        12
39 22    12        12
40 22     3        15
41 22     3        15
42 22     6        18
43 22     7        19
44 22     8        20
45 22     9        21
46 22     9        21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
output_desired %>%
   mutate(gr = cumsum(c(0,diff(month)<0))*12+month, .by = id)

   id month month_new gr
1  11     8         8  8
2  11     8         8  8
3  11     8         8  8
4  11     9         9  9
5  11    10        10 10
6  11    10        10 10
7  11    10        10 10
8  11    11        11 11
9  11    11        11 11
10 11    11        11 11
11 11    11        11 11
12 11    12        12 12
13 11    12        12 12
14 11     1        13 13
15 11     1        13 13
16 11     1        13 13
17 11     1        13 13
18 11     1        13 13
19 11     2        14 14
20 11     2        14 14
21 11     3        15 15
22 11     3        15 15
23 11     6        18 18
24 11     6        18 18
25 11     8        20 20
26 11     8        20 20
27 11     8        20 20
28 11     9        21 21
29 11    11        23 23
30 22     1         1  1
31 22     1         1  1
32 22     2         2  2
33 22     2         2  2
34 22     6         6  6
35 22     7         7  7
36 22     9         9  9
37 22     9         9  9
38 22    12        12 12
39 22    12        12 12
40 22     3        15 15
41 22     3        15 15
42 22     6        18 18
43 22     7        19 19
44 22     8        20 20
45 22     9        21 21
46 22     9        21 21
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great if each month only appears once. However, in my dataset I have multiple observations per month within the first year. I did not mention that in my original question, but edited it now!

Comment: Awesome! Works quite well! However, it does not work when for the same id the same month (e.g. 10) happens in the first and the second year. Another case the code cannot correctly calculate is when there is gap in the months after 12, i.e. from 12 directly to 2. Please see my edited question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add `1:n() - 1` to the first input for each `id`.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(new = first(input) + 1:n() - 1, .by = id)
```

Comment: This also works fine. However, how would it work when each year has multiple osbervations and only months in the second year should be increased by 12?